# Read all internal memory images in android though mediastore

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-image, mediastore

i am able to read all external images though mediastore in Android, but i want to read all images of internal memory also.

Plz Help..!!

Answer (score 0):

The only images on internal memory that you can read are your own images, that you placed there yourself for your own app. Since you know where those are, you can read them in yourself (e.g., use Java file I/O to list files in a directory).

Comment: thnxx a lot for valuable guide...you mean we can not read all other images which are showing in gallery. in my app i want to show all images of gallery. because few android phones has efficient internal memory and might be there is no sd card. so how can we read files of those phones.

Comment: @user1: "you mean we can not read all other images which are showing in gallery" -- those are on external storage and are indexed by `MediaStore`. "because few android phones has efficient internal memory and might be there is no sd card" -- an "sd card" has little to do with external storage nowadays. "External storage" != "removable storage". http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal